# Time taken to complete Copycluster in Vertica?

Tags: database, vertica

We have a 10 node cluster with about 25TB of data. We want to create a DR with same configuration and use copycluster to transfer the data.

How long would it take for the copycluster to complete over 10Gbps network?

In the Vertica Documentation its mentioned for Bulk Loads:

> Vertica can load about 30-50GB/hour/node for a 1-Ksafe projection design

Does the same apply for CopyCluster too? Is this irrespective of the Network bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

The network will be the greatest bottleneck.

The comparison with bulk load makes little sense - working with "vbr" is working with Vertica ROS files, not with database objects over the SQL interface. That's why also the number of nodes and the names of the database nodes must correspond in copycluster.

To estimate how long it takes, you have to know whether the 25TB you mention are the tables' audit size (how much space would they take if you exported them to CSV files) or the size of their ROS files.

The time it will take can be calculated when you know how many GB per unit of time you can transfer from one cluster to the other, and you know the total ROS file size.

Can't say much more with the info above...

Comment: 25TB is the compressed size, the size on Disk. The audit size is about 54Tb.
For network throughput value, since we have a 10Gbps bandwidth, we have about 2TB/hour transfer rate i believe.